# Google Spreadsheet, copy column in sheet to column in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to have the entire contents of a column in one sheet show in another sheet.

For example I have **column D** in **sheet2** that I want to show in **column A** of **sheet1**.
Something like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet2!D)
```

But that gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use:

`=ArrayFormula('Sheet2'!D:D)`

Comment: you can also use ={Sheet2!D:D}

Comment: How can we select columns which are not in sequence? For example, how can I copy the  columns A,C,E ?

Answer (score 13):

If you want to share columns across separate files, you can use:

```
=importrange("17s-yYzX8GYvyA2PorY2PLaZ5OpFi14wU0ugAyTIrL24","Sheet1!G:J")
```

where the first string is the key of the sheet file that you want to import from. You can copy that directly from the URL e.g. `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17s-yYzX8GYvyA2PorY2PLaZ5OpFi14wU0ugAyTIrL24/edit#gid=0`. The second string is the name of the sheet in the source file and in the example `G:J` means import columns G through J.

Answer (score 10):

```
={'Sheet2'!X:X}
```

Needs single-quotes around the sheet name.

Comment: `={(Sheet1!X:X)}` will work in this case too, but the quotes make it more clear

Answer (score 5):

**More info**

Both two formulas display the column like a Row, it "Transpose" the group of cells.

```
- ArrayFormula('Sheet'!X:X)
- Importrange("sheetkey","nameSheet!x:x")
```

But this beatifull formula copy the column without changing the direction.

```
- {Sheet2!X:X}
```

Comment: Brilliant, most solutions are way too complicated. This worked like a charm.